# Not able to call any function from materialize.js file

Tags: javascript, materialize

This is the first I'm using materialized design for my cordova based windows phone app.
In static html page,everything is working fine with materialized functionality(like sidebar, tabs,modal..etc).

But,loading templates dynamically, then calling the js related functions for materialze is a big problem!.The problem is I'm not able to call any function from materialize file after it is being loaded.

This is how I'm loading js files for materialize:

```
<script src="lib/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>        
<script src="lib/js/materialize.js"></script>
```

I tried calling `$(".button-collapse").sideNav();`, `$("ul.tabs").tabs();` from console(after necessary templates are being loaded),but I'm getting the error `$(..).sideNav is not a function`, same for `tabs`also.

I put break point in `$.fn.tabs` function which is in materialze.js, while refreshing the page, then it hits that function, but after everything loaded, if i try calling the that function again, it is giving the error `$(..).tabs() is not function`.

So, I'm stuck here. 
Is there anything I'm missing?. how can I make this work?

**EDIT**:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <title>FTMobile</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
        <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainContainer"></div>

        <script src="lib/bin/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/bin/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/bin/materialize.js"></script>

        <script data-main="js/cordovaConfig.js" src="lib/js/require.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The template:

```html
<script id="infoPageTpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12">
                    <ul class="tabs">
                        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#taginfo">Tag info</a></li>
                        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#prodinfo">Product info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="taginfo" class="col s12">
                    <ul class="collection">
                    {{#each tagInfoData}}
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="title">{{attributName}}</span>
                            <p>{{attributeValue}}</p>
                        </li>
                    {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="prodinfo" class="col s12">
                    <ul class="collection">
                    {{#each productInfoData}}
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="title">{{attributeName}}</span>
                            <p>{{attributeValue}}</p>
                        </li>
                    {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Js code:

```js
define([
    "require",
    "exports",
    "marionette",
    "backbone",
    "underscore",
    "js/applicationUtilities/commonFunctions"
    ],function(
        require,
        exports,
        Marionette,
        Backbone,
        _,
        commonFunctions
    ){
        "use strict";
        exports.TagandProductInfoView=Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            render:function(){
                var tagJson = this.model.get("currentTag").tagJson,
                    tagInfoData=this.buildDataForTemplating(tagJson.tagInfo),
                    productInfoData=this.buildDataForTemplating(tagJson.productInfo);

                this.el.innerHTML= commonFunctions.templateCompilation("infoPageTpl",{"tagInfoData":tagInfoData,"productInfoData":productInfoData});
            },
            onShow:function(){
                $('ul.tabs').tabs();
            },
            buildDataForTemplating:function(infoData){
                var data=[];
                for(var key in infoData){
                    data.push({
                        attributeName:key,
                        attributeValue:infoData[key]
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Do you have more code to show? It should work for tabs and sidebar at least (I found some issues for some dynamically added content but not these)

Comment: @angelwally, I added my code.

Comment: Coule you try adding jquery in your require define statement? It might be the issue.